# How hard is it to find a Three Floyds Dark Lord?

Tags: imperal-stout

I'm not looking for any specific vintage or special variant. Just the standard [Dark Lord RIS](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/three-floyds-dark-lord-russian-imperial-stout/15917/).

I'm also well aware of the fact that Three Floyds has limited distribution in the Midwest, and I'm for sure not going to find it on the West Coast.

However, I sometimes travel back to Ohio, where they do distribute. What are my chances of walking into a decent bottle shop back there and finding one of these? Do i have a good shot, or is this a very seasonal brew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know it is only sold on dark Lord day at the brewery and you need to buy tickets.  I've only had it once from someone who went.

[Three Floyds Brewing cuts off packaged sales on Dark Lord Day](http://www.chicagotribune.com/suburbs/post-tribune/news/ct-ptb-dark-lord-day-st-0327-20150328-story.html)

Comment: That is REALLY not the answer I wanted, but I think you're right. Darn it. Thanks for the info!